# Using Merge.xts function to merge multiple xts files together

Tags: r

I am having a problem trying to merge different xts files together properly.Below are the files I am trying to merge.I was hoping to use the merge.xts function but am unsure how to format it. Any hep is greatly appreciated!

```
XOM.rtn <- monthlyReturn(XOM $ XOM.Adjusted, subset=NULL, type='log', leading=TRUE)
MSFT.rtn <- monthlyReturn(MSFT $ MSFT.Adjusted, subset=NULL, type='log', leading=TRUE)
JNJ.rtn <- monthlyReturn(JNJ $ JNJ.Adjusted, subset=NULL, type='log', leading=TRUE)
GE.rtn <- monthlyReturn(GE $ GE.Adjusted, subset=NULL, type='log', leading=TRUE)
CVX.rtn <- monthlyReturn(CVX $ CVX.Adjusted, subset=NULL, type='log', leading=TRUE)
WFC.rtn <- monthlyReturn(WFC $ WFC.Adjusted, subset=NULL, type='log', leading=TRUE)
PG.rtn <- monthlyReturn(PG $ PG.Adjusted, subset=NULL, type='log', leading=TRUE)
JPM.rtn <- monthlyReturn(JPM $ JPM.Adjusted, subset=NULL, type='log', leading=TRUE)
VZ.rtn <- monthlyReturn(VZ $ VZ.Adjusted, subset=NULL, type='log', leading=TRUE)
PFE.rtn <- monthlyReturn(PFE $ PFE.Adjusted, subset=NULL, type='log', leading=TRUE)
T.rtn <- monthlyReturn(T $ T.Adjusted, subset=NULL, type='log', leading=TRUE)
IBM.rtn <- monthlyReturn(IBM $ IBM.Adjusted, subset=NULL, type='log', leading=TRUE)
MRK.rtn <- monthlyReturn(MRK $ MRK.Adjusted, subset=NULL, type='log', leading=TRUE)
BAC.rtn <- monthlyReturn(BAC $ BAC.Adjusted, subset=NULL, type='log', leading=TRUE)
ORCL.rtn <- monthlyReturn(ORCL $ ORCL.Adjusted, subset=NULL, type='log', leading=TRUE)
PM.rtn <- monthlyReturn(PM $ PM.Adjusted, subset=NULL, type='log', leading=TRUE)
INTC.rtn <- monthlyReturn(INTC $ INTC.Adjusted, subset=NULL, type='log', leading=TRUE)
DIS.rtn <- monthlyReturn(DIS $ DIS.Adjusted, subset=NULL, type='log', leading=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the objects into a `list` and then do the `merge`

```
library(xts)
out <- Reduce(function(...) merge(...),  mget(ls(pattern = 'rtn\\$')))
```